# There is no result after git push -u origin master

Tags: git

Thank you for answering my question.

so, I'm trying to push to GitHub, like I attached picture, but it doesn't show any results.

[image: Picture in git bash]

what I did was

```
git init loc-git
vim f1.txt
git add .
git commit -m "add a"
git remote add origin <My URL>
git remote -v
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: In your screenshot, it looks like you forgot to commit.  You just staged.  But in your list of commands you did commit.  Could that be the issue?

Comment: The problem was that I didn't check some of the default settings during the git installation. Like, we all tend to click on the "next" button to leave without paying much attention to what is being asked of us.  But we are asked to choose the "Credential Helper" which helps us to fetch or save something in our storage. So, I used this command: git config remote.origin.url "https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/USERNAME/REPONAME.git" and it works.